# Java Frame shows my screen

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I am starting to learn how to make graphics in Java. But if I draw something in my Frame and I run the program. those parts of the Frame where I did not draw anything there is the picture of the Frame running behind my Program. hw can I avoid this?

```
package de.sarah;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Framemg extends JFrame{

public Framemg() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Zeichnen mit Java");
    setSize(400, 300);
    setBackground(Color.yellow);
    setVisible(true);
}
public void paint(Graphics g) {
     g.drawString( "Hellooo", 120, 60 );
}
}

package de.sarah;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Insets;

public class Main{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Framemg Frame = new Framemg();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't override paint() of a JFrame.

Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent(...)` method of a JPanel. Then you add the panel to the frame.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples to get you started.

Comment: @Sarah, Glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark so people know the problem has been solved.